# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING (Trying HTML inside php)

Tags: php, html, tstringgrid

so i have a php code to track my game server if it's online or offline.
But i tried with html inside the echo but it outputs the famous T_String error.

My code:

```
    <table border="1" bgcolor="#fff">
  <tr>
<td>SERVER</td>
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("some ip", an port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp)
{
    echo "<h1><td style="background-color:red">Offline</td></h1>";
}
else;
{
    echo "<h1><td style="background-color:green">Online</td></h1>";
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

It says on line 26 which is     `echo "<h1><td style="background-color:red">Offline</td></h1>";`

Comment: Escape double quotes when encapsulated with double quotes `echo "<h1><td style=\"background-color:red\">Offline</td></h1>";` or use single quotes `echo "<h1><td style='background-color:red'>Offline</td></h1>";` Or.. or... or. There's another way, but this will suffice; for now. Oh, and the semi-colon in `else;` remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape those `"` inside the echoed string (and also remove the `;` after `else`):

```
<table border="1" bgcolor="#fff">
<tr>
<td>SERVER</td>
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("some ip", an port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp)
{
    echo "<h1><td style=\"background-color:red\">Offline</td></h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1><td style=\"background-color:green\">Online</td></h1>";
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```